# How to add a custom button (image) in an onclick event?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, button

I'd like some help, because I am trying to learn AJAX and I'm stuck. So I have this code here and everything is right, when i press the buttons the information from the PHP file are displayed perfectly.

```
`<form>
   <input type="button" value="req" onclick="fetch('hotels.php?select=1')">
   <input type="button" value="req2" onclick="fetch2('hotels.php?select=2')">
   <input type="button" value="req3" onclick="fetch3('hotels.php?select=3')">
</form>`
```

So what I needed to ask is the following: Can I replace the plain classic onclick button with a custom one that I've made in Da Button Factory? I have tried to change the input type to an image, but the problem is that the page is refreshing, when I click it (On the other hand when I just have the classic button onclick it doesn't refresh and the infos are displayed). My programming teacher told me that it must not refresh, as we are working on AJAX right now. Here is what I've tried to do

```
<input type="image" src="button_london.png" alt="randomtext" value="req2" onclick="fetch2('hotels.php?select=2')">
```

Any tips?

Comment: Please provide more details, specifically what the `fetch`, `fetch2`, etc. functions look like.

Answer (score 0):

Input image by default acts as a submit button. If the input type image does the job for you, simply add return false after your onclick function to prevent refreshing.

```
<input type="image" value="req" onclick="fetch('hotels.php?select=1');return false;">
```